# WPF ShowDialog() doesn't return if owner window is programatically closed

Tags: .net, wpf

Suppose I have two windows, a MainWindow and a TestWindow. Then I do this:

```
private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        var window1 = new TestWindow();
        window1.Show();

        var timer = new Timer();
        timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3).TotalMilliseconds;
        timer.Elapsed += (s, e1) => Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action) (() => window1.Close()));
        timer.Start();

        var window2 = new TestWindow();
        window2.Owner = window1;
        window2.ShowDialog();
    }
```

After 3 seconds both TestWindows are closed, but the application hangs. Any idea why?

Answer (score 2):

This issue has been reported: https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/issues/277

Apparently, the window on top of the stack (`window2`) doesn't get closed when you call `Close()` on `window1` like you would expect.

This behaviour means that you need to make sure that you close the windows in the reverse order that you opened them, i.e. call `Close()` on `window2` before you close `window1`:

```
var window1 = new TestWindow();
window1.Show();

var window2 = new TestWindow();

var timer = new Timer();
timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3).TotalMilliseconds;
timer.Elapsed += (s, e1) => Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => { window2.Close(); window1.Close(); }));
timer.Start();

window2.Owner = window1;
window2.ShowDialog();
```